# How to access object property using variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Code below doesn't work. How can I dynamically get slides of obj? If I use const key instead of let key, it works, but I need to use let to change it dynamically.

```
let key = 'slides'
const obj = {
   slides: []
}

console.log(obj[key])
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not type-safe, `key` is just any `string` not necessarily `'slides'`. The correct fix depends on what behaviour you're looking for - do you want any string to be able to index `obj` or only valid properties to be assigned to `key`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi. At least any string. But only valid are good too. How is it possible?

Comment: Start with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving should be:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ slides: never[]; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ slides: never[]; }'

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, the error is related to the type of  the `key` variable.

The type has to match with the type of the object.

```
const obj = {
   slides: []
}

let key1 = 'slides' // type of key is 'string'
console.log(obj[key1]) // Error

const key2 = 'slides' // type of key is "slides"
console.log(obj[key2]) // Works

let key3: 'slides' = 'slides' // type of key is "slides"
console.log(obj[key3]) // Works

let key4: keyof typeof obj = 'slides' // type of key is "slides"
console.log(obj[key3]) // Works
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHEA2AlgCYCmEAXDANoC6mAvppnibANYkCeAjKjAOT5iZfjAD0YmFE4AHEnABmMDpxgEIA6ACcCYAOb9MoSCBYA6PCD0AKBIioruNAJTjJAUS1aQWpsejKXABMfIKEpBCiElKy8iBKKmoaAERCEclG4BCmJBZWtkgOwS5uMADqPmwQTCzsXADMlGHCkaFpIqXScoqBquowqeFkGf45eTZ2RZz1JdEVWlU1rL0ALJQq8TFym3ZtQ63RXXEJXEkD7RAjWWOWE4UqM65zlRBAA)

If you need to change it "dynamically" as you put it, then the best option is most likely to use `keyof typeof`. This will mean that if you add fields to `obj` that they will be included in the options for your key.

As an example:

```
const obj = {
   a: "A",
   b: "B"
}

let key: keyof typeof obj = "a" // type of key is "a" | "b" (meaning "a" or "b")
console.log(obj[key]) // Works - Logs A

key = "b";
console.log(obj[key]) // Works - Logs B
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHBDAXDAEQCCRANNjvIUQEJGYC+mmANgKawDWHAnoV58QAMxhQ+ABw6i4SVMVxEYAehXipHOGKEwAlhEXKAPsXiNQkEJwB0bEAHMAFAkQBtIQF0AlKvUB1EAAnbkMAWhgAGUdDElZdNCJzAG5MSwhrDjtHFyQPfh8-GECQ8KiYmDogA)

Note: if you had defined the type for `obj` separately, then `keyof` would have been enough.
E.g.:

```
interface MyObjectType {
   a: string;
   b: string;
}

const obj: MyObjectType = {
   a: "A",
   b: "B"
}

let key: keyof MyObjectType = "a" // type of key is keyof MyObjectType
console.log(obj[key]) // Works - Logs A

key = "b";
console.log(obj[key]) // Works - Logs B
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMAFXQAcUBvAKGVrgC5kBnMKUAcwG4bbtGW2ILlQC+VKggD2IFskl5GGHPkIlyyALzJqtZA2QAiAIIGAND2R9DAIQOjxAGwhhkAawjpG79JJhoseATEZChaBnAGyAD0UchgIXJ+3sjATG4evv7KQWoQEtJMkk4AdA6S7AAU8rgA2t4AugCU0bEA6pJQrmkAtMgAMuVpRuLJYdgG3FIyRRCl5VV4dR5NLcjtnT39g8jWQA)

For more info, see:

- [Keyof Type Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)
- [Typeof Type Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)